# Files downloaded from Thunderbird will be stored in var/run/user

Tags: email, thunderbird, downloads

Whenever I want to download sent via Thunderbird, it automatically offers me a var/run/user/1000/doc track, though in preferences I checked that it should ask me where I want the file to be stored. When I want the files always to be stored on the desktop, Thunderbird does not accept this choice, change it to var/run/user..
In between I have loads of files stored in var/run/user/100/doc/any.number - and not in the places where I want them to be. When I delete them, they are also deleted in the proper place - so I am afraid to do anything now...
Can anybody help?
I installed Thunderbird with Flatpak. Version 115.3.2., Using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Mate 1.26
Thanks in advance
B.

Comment: You may want to use the APT version, which will not have these limitations. Otherwise, you have to remove the restrictions of the Flatpak sandbox.